# npm rebuild node-sass hang

Tags: npm, node-sass

[image]

```
Node version : 8.16. 



npm: 6.4.1



yarn: 1.17.3
```

postinstall: npm rebuild node-sass hangs

Tried with multiple solutions,but not works

Answer (score 0):

```
Yarn add -D node-sass
```

adding node-sass as dependency package fixed the issue.